# Write an R data frame to an Excel file maintaining Excel's default date format

Tags: r, excel, lubridate, openxlsx, writexl

If you open up a new instance of *Excel 2016* and enter a date in the following format `8/15` it will output in Excel like this:

[image: excel image]

*Excel's* format menu identifies this as `Custom > d-mmm`. Now let's move on to the R part of this question. I'll create a simple data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = as.Date(c("2021-01-01", "2021-02-15")), col2 = c(3, 9))
#>         col1 col2
#> 1 2021-01-01    3
#> 2 2021-02-15    9
```

**I want to** write this data frame to an Excel file, and **default to *Excel's* `Custom > d-mmm` date format** (as shown above).

My first attempt is quite generic, and uses the writexl package:

```
library(writexl)
write_xlsx(df, "df.xlsx")
```

[image: excel image]

*Excel* ends up reading these dates as *Excel's* `yyyy-mm-dd` format, not the `Custom > d-mmm` format I want. Let me get a little more sophisticated and try and use the openxlsx package to get what I want:

```
library(openxlsx)
options(xlsx.date.format = "d-mmm")
write.xlsx(df, file = "df.xlsx", asTable = TRUE)
```

[image: excel image]

This time, the output is in the *Excel* format `Date > *3/14/2012`. How can I get the date to be recognized in *Excel*, in the *Excel* `Custom > d-mmm` format? The output would look like this, and should not involve any manual *Excel* steps:

[image: excel image]

Answer (score 1):

Apply the global formatting syntax as per the documentation

```
options(openxlsx.dateFormat = "d-mmm")
```

---

Documentation:

```
https://rdrr.io/cran/openxlsx/man/openxlsx.html
```